# How to change the text color of context menu item

Tags: android, mobile, menu, colors, contextmenu

I have made a custom list in android and added a context menu to it (on long press).

I am not able to change the text color of the menu items.

How do I change its item color to blue?

Comment: can you please post the xml file

Comment: this is how I have added:

`@Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) 
    {
        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
        menu.add(0, DELETE_ID, 0, R.string.menu_delete);
    }`

Comment: Check this link http://gurushya.com/android-context-menus/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you have created a custom list , you are calling method for adding item in list like addItem() or setText(). So whatever you do just apply below code while adding the item.

```
Spannable wordtoSpan = new SpannableString("Your Item Name");        

wordtoSpan.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLUE), 0, wordtoSpan.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE); //Your color code instead Color.BLUE
```